# how can i put multiple records into 1 record in mysql

Tags: mysql

I was trying to move multiple records from one table to one record in another. with MYSQL,I tried Group_concat(), Concat() Group by, and Stored Procedure to breakdown the data and regroup. Unfortunately, my attempts have failed. I know you can help me because you are the experts. I thank you in advance. Please see image I attached.

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you need an output in that form, use a `VIEW`.

Comment: `SELECT Material, Sum(Qty in Jan), Sum(Qty In Feb), etc.. FROM Table1 GROUP BY Material;` should do the trick. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question though?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you require aggregation here, something like:

```
select Matrial, max(Qty_In_Jan) Qty_In_Jan, max(Qty_In_feb) Qty_In_feb....
from t
group by Matrial;
```

Comment: hi, Stu you are the best! I thank you so much.